# consolidating calls to jquery ui's dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

So I have these two `dialog()` calls:

```
$('#dialog').dialog();
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'width', 500);
```

Is there a way to consolidate that down into one? I tried this without success:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    option: [{ width: 500 }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from a project I am working on.

```
$( "#username_availability_dialog" ).dialog({
closeOnEscape: false,
resizable: false,
height:120,
width: "48%",
modal: true,
buttons: {
"OK": function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
$('#dealName').val('');
$("#dealsForm [name='dealName']").focus();
return false;
},
Cancel: function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
window.location.reload();
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the square brackets or the `option` method when initializing the dialog widget using an object to store the options.

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    width: 500
});
```

The format you were using to set options actually REQUIRES that the widget be initialized beforehand.

[jQuery-UI Dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width) "width" option